# client scripting vs server scripting

Tags: scripting, client

What is the difference between client side scripting and server side scripting?

I know that that with server scripting a link will create a dynamic page based on a number of conditions usually within PHP. I also know that with client side scripting all the code is already on the users browser and that the page will alter based on the user's input.

Is there any other tidbits of knowledge on this that anyone can offer me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side scripts can be manipulated by the user, you do not have access to a databases, it may cause different results in different clients... There are a lot of differences. Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: i was more just wondering generally... not anything tooo too deep. Just an over-view. I think i understand it now though.. thanks for your response. upvoted.